# Render fails after a few frames

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

For some reason, the render of my current projects fails after rendering 5-10 frames. I am using cycles, have tried experimental and supported. I have tried many variations of sample size at 256x256 tiles and cannot find anything specific in my scene that would be causing this issue...

I have rendered on Optix with an rtx2070.

I have also tried CUDA with 2070 and 1060 checked.

I am attaching the .blend file below if anyone can please help.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cg6OjQ5zyL_Ox7_6my0Z0iRgTUfqJqkb/view?usp=sharing

[image: screenshot of the scene]

Answer (score 1):

First, some statistics:
Your file is 255MB big, the scene has ~780k vertices, the shaders take several minutes to compile, and it used 2GB memory.

In the first step, I would reduce the number of vertices. You have a car driving on a long road and the camera is chasing it, looking at the tires... a great animation. So the car and tires are in the focus. But you don't need tires that have a total of 500k(!) vertices. Remove the *Subdivision Surface* modifiers. The wheels are spinning when the car drives and you can't see the tire tread at speed anyway.

The same applies to the interior of the car. The car has black opaque windows. You can't see the interior. Why is there a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with 2 levels?
The car can have a level 1 *Subdivision Surface* and you won't see a difference.

If you do this the scene has only ~240k vertices. Half of it has the car, the other half is used for the environment.

(Side note: The car looks a bit too small or the house too big)

Answer (score 0):

It renders normal. It already rendered to 10-th frame. But I have Intel Celeron G3900 and GTX 1060 3GB. I put in preference CUDA - NVIDIA GTX 1060.
Probably you have too many pirate software or junk running program. Try to have "clean hard driver"(or SSD) with windows and blender. And run on it only for work.